# D3 Slows Down Drawing Dashed Lines

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using D3 to create a svg element and draw a bunch of open splines (using cardinal interpolation).  I'm drawing approximately 30 splines, each of which contain approximately 75-150 vertex points... so in general this should be pretty easy.  However, I have a brush element on my page that I've implemented as a slider ([similar to this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972)).  At the moment, the brush event doesn't cause any redrawing on the lines... it merely recalculates the position of the handle.  Since it's not really causing it to redraw anything, I would expect that the process of moving the handle on the brush would be very fast (the slider would have no lag)... however, I found that when it's drawing all of the lines with a dashed stroked array, that it's quite sluggish.  If I comment out the line which specifies the dashed array so that the lines are simply solid strokes, then the brush movement is much faster.  Is there a reason why this is happening?  As I said, I'm not having the brush "redraw" anything, so I don't know why there would be any performance difference... but it definitely seems to lag when it's drawing dashed lines (when compared to solid lines).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sample code or JSFiddle would be useful here